# AMP article incorrectly cached: article content not displayed

Tags: amp-html, cache-control, google-news

We've recently developed AMP versions for some of our articles and although they are available in Google News results, they appear incorrectly: the article content is not displayed as well as the category tags.

Here's an example with an article that passes the Google and AMP validation tests:

- working desktop version: https://www.ecranlarge.com/films/news/1367186-apres-marvel-martin-scorsese-attaque-netflix-le-streaming-et-les-algorithmes.amp
- broken cached version available on smartphones: https://www-ecranlarge-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.ecranlarge.com/films/news/1367186-apres-marvel-martin-scorsese-attaque-netflix-le-streaming-et-les-algorithmes.amp

Here's a screenshot of the cached version in case I fix this page in the meantime: https://www.imghost.fr/image/or4i

Eventhough I can fix it by refreshing the cache, I mostly would like to know why it has been cached like this and find a way to prevent this.

Has anyone else ever experienced this issue, and did you find any reason and/or solution?

Thanks!

Comment: i've clicked both links and do not see the difference. what is the problem you see?

Comment: My bad, I've written a script to refresh the cache in the meantime so this example must have been fixed.

Here's another example:

    - working version: https://www.ecranlarge.com/films/news/1367136-marvel-comment-le-docteur-fatalis-pourrait-se-retrouver-face-a-loki-sur-disney.amp
    - broken cached version available on smartphones: https://www-ecranlarge-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.ecranlarge.com/films/news/1367136-marvel-comment-le-docteur-fatalis-pourrait-se-retrouver-face-a-loki-sur-disney.amp

I'll also update my original post.

Comment: well, if you can refresh the cache, then that's the solution (nice work; many struggle with this step). there are many cases where the cache is different from the source, and there are many reasons why that is so. when you see an error, do as you did - refresh the cache.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The thing is that it almost every single AMP page is incorrectly cached and as we publish many articles on a daily basis, it's a bit tedious to manually correct the problem, that's why I'd rather want to prevent it (or at least know what the hell is wrong with my code!).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you're having trouble - the pages seem to just have been cached while they were broken (from a content point of view at least - they are still valid AMP pages).

The only fix would be to for the content to be stale on the cache. This happens automatically over a period of time, however you can [programmatically request](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache) a reindex to speed things up.

source: work at Google on AMP